# Как перевести текст в ansi из UTF-8 без BOM?

Tags: ansi, delphi

Собственно имеется текст который лежит в переменной типа tstringlist. Я его сохраняю скажем в ***.html но кодировка стоит UTF-8 без BOM. И поэтому появляются кракозябры, а в анси всё норм. Как перевести?

Answer (score 2):

В Д7 есть прекрасная функция `AnsiToUTF8`

Comment: а играет роль что с BOM или без него?

Comment: Функция про БОМ ничего не знает. И его наличием не интересуется.

Comment: вот еще вариант, болше похожий на правду :) 

    function cp1251ToUTF8(ansi: AnsiString): UTF8String;
    var
      ustr: AnsiString;
      wcharcount: Integer;
    begin
      wcharcount := Length(ansi);
      SetLength(ustr, wcharcount*2);
      SetLength(Result, wcharcount*2);
      wcharcount := MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, PChar(ansi), wcharcount, PWideChar(ustr), 2*wcharcount);
      if wcharcount > 0 then
        UnicodeToUtf8(PChar(Result), Length(Result), PWideChar(ustr), wcharcount)
      else
       raise Exception.Create('Can not translate to Unicode');
    end;